# array_push without array as parameter?

Tags: php, arrays, function

This is my code

```
$items = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17);
    $numCols = 4;
    $result = ArrayVals($items,$numCols);
    echo $result;
    function ArrayVals($items,$numCols) {
        $minRow = floor(count($items)/$numCols);
        $remaining = count($items) % $numCols;
        $cCount = array();
        for ($i = 0;$i<$numCols;$i++) {
            if ($i < $remaining) {
                array_push($cCount,$minRow+1);
            } else {
                array_push($colCount,$minRow);
            }
        }
        $listString = '';
        $count = 0;
        for ($i = 0;$i<count($cCount);$i++) {
            $listString = $listString . "<ul>";
            for ($j = 0;$j<$cCount[$i];$j++) {
                $listString = $listString . '<li>' . $items[$count] . '</li>';
                $count = $count + 1;
            }
            $listString = $listString . '</ul>';
        }
        return $listString;
```

i am getting the

> Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in
>   C:\UniServer\www\RnD\Test2\t2.php on line 20

how should i solve it

Comment: `$colCount` !== `$cCount`

Comment: define  `$colCount = array();` above `for loop` .

Comment: What is `$colCount` within `array_push($colCount,$minRow);`

Comment: ^ i thinl it must be `else {  array_push($cCount,$minRow);  }`

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the **$colCount** as **array()** before for loop

```
$colCount=array();
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$colCount` not defined in its scope. Initialize the variable `$colCount` in `function ArrayVals().`

Answer (score 0):

`$colCount`  is undefined . `array_push` expects first parameter to be an array .

[Read manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)